# Custom bash/cron script to clean sandbox folder: scan and remove anything older than 3 days

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory on my system which I like to use as a sandbox area where I can dump things- unzipped downloads, screenshots with annotations- any files or directories which I *know I only need temporarily*. To save the hassle of continously having to manually clean this directory, I am running a bash script that deletes anything older than 3 days, run from a cron that runs every 10 minutes:

```
find "/mnt/a/Temp/" -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find "/mnt/a/Temp/" -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

So this looks within all folders recursively and deletes all files older than 3 days. It then checks if that has resulted in any empty directories being left behind, and if so, it deletes those too.

I thought this was working pretty well until I noticed a problem: If I download a zip file from the net for example and extract it, while the creation date of the extracted folders/files shows the date I extracted them, the actual modification date of the files show the original date they were made by their author. Depending on when they were uploaded to their respository this could be years in the past (in my case they were from 2016).

This has the unfortunate effect that if I extract a zip file in my sandbox directory, it instantly (within 10 minutes) vanishes. I don't want that, I want it to hang around for 3 days like everything else in there.

Can I modify my script so that:

- It firstly looks at the **modification date** of all the directories that are direct children of the main sandbox directory, and *only scans inside the ones with a modification date older than 3 days*
- Of those directories older than 3 days, it wipes them, and everything in them, completely.
- Any files residing within the top level of the sandbox directory (ie. direct children of it) are scanned and deleted according to modification date as before.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

(Probably not relevant, but I am actually on Windows running bash with WSL)

Comment: `-atime` is not an option? You can actually have files, which you don't modify, but still access. ; )

Comment: @KamilCuk actually, no. Because I would have to enable access time on ntfs on my Windows system for this to work- I think- and it would cause problems with syncing (I also use Resilio Sync on this Sandbox directory). Otherwise it's a good suggestion though- thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, and other Unix-like OSes, a possible solution to the problem is to use `-ctime` instead of `-mtime` in the first `find` command.  The 'ctime' on Unix is the "time of last status change" (**not** the creation time).  See the Wikipedia [stat (system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) article for more information.  The 'ctime' is often the same as the 'mtime', but when a file's 'mtime' is set to an earlier time (e.g. as part of a download) the 'ctime' should be the time that the 'mtime' change was made (in the case of a download, very close to the time the download completed).

Unfortunately, the fact that you are using WSL on Windows may be relevant.  NTFS does have an equivalent of the Unix 'ctime': the "MFT Entry modified time".  See [How can I display all 8 NTFS timestamps?](https://superuser.com/questions/973547/how-can-i-display-all-8-ntfs-timestamps).  However, standard Windows API functions can't access it, and most Windows tools don't report it.  The good news is that some Unix-derived tools can and do report it.  The Cygwin tools are one example.  Under Cygwin, changing `-mtime` to `-ctime` should work.  I don't know if WSL uses the "MFT Entry modified time" as the 'ctime' though.  I suggest you try it and see.

The answer to the "Can I modify my script so that: ..." question is yes :-).  It's more complicated than using `-ctime` though, and I'd do it only if using `-ctime` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll run some experiments and get back to you... ;)